# Recursively working with Antlr4 parsers and listeners

Tags: parsing, recursion, antlr, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I'm working on a project to parse a boolean-like DSL and convert it to a specific JSON format. I've constructed a general hierarchy of classes to accomplish this task, but I'm not sure where to begin transforming the parse tree into the data structures I want.

Here is my grammar:

```
grammar filter;

filter: category EOF;

category
    : LPAREN category RPAREN # ParenCat
    | category AND category # CatAndBlock
    | label COLON expression # CategoryBlock
    ;

expression
    : LPAREN expression RPAREN  # ParenExp
    | NOT expression            # NotBlock
    | expression AND expression  # AndBlock
    | expression OR expression   # OrBlock
    | atom # AtomExp
    ;

label
    : ALPHANUM
    ;

atom 
    : ALPHANUM
    ;
```

Here is an example of an input string:

> ( cat1:( ( (1 OR 2 ) AND ( 3 ) ) ) ) AND cat2:( 4 )

With the following parse tree:

[image]

Here is a rough sketch of the class hierarchy I hope to implement (each class has their own 'write' method):

```
CategoryContainer: LinkedList<Category>
    Category: LinkedList<ItemBlock> list, String categoryName #CategoryBlock
        ItemBlock: LinkedList<ItemBlock> list, String type
            AndBlock extends ItemBlock
            OrBlock extends ItemBlock
            NotBlock extends ItemBlock
            AtomBlock extends ItemBlock: list = null, String value = "atomValue"
```

I've been looking through some tutorials for listeners, and have a pretty solid idea of what's going on. However, I can't seem to find much information on a recursive problem like the one I'm working with. Do you have any tips on how I can get started?

Edit: Clarification on what I'm hoping to achieve,

For an example input String:

> cat1:(4 AND 5) AND cat2:( 4 )

I want to recursively generate the following classes (with bracket-list-notation representing the respective linked lists):

```
CategoryContainer: 
[
    Category: categoryName="cat1", # CategoryBlock Listener
    [ 
        AndBlock: [ AtomBlock: value="4", AtomBlock: value="5" ] # AndBlock Listener
    ],
    Category: categoryName="cat2", # CategoryBlock Listener
    [
        AtomBlock: value="4" # AtomBlock Listener
    ]
]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what exactly you want to do? You have given an example parse tree so maybe try to formulate in words or pseudo-code what you want the listener to do...

Comment: Basically, I want to transform the input data into the class hierarchy, using the parsed output. Perhaps only specifying listener was a little vague. I've updated the end of my post with a little elaboration. Let me know if it's still too vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention that you already have reviewed the Listener pattern, here's what I would suggest:

1. Create a listener and hook it up to a TreeWalker
2. Listener supports overrides for "Enter" (going down the tree) and "Exit" (coming back up the tree) events.  Create a simple hardcoded override for each "Exit event available.
3. Run the application.  You'll see the depth-first traversal and recursion at work.
4. From there, update your "Exit" event overrides to add to your linked list structure, or a stack-based structure also works well for unrolling recursion.
5. In either case, when you're done, you'll have something very similar to the structure you proposed.

Using the Listener and Exit events, the recursion and traversal is taken care of for you.  You'll find it very useful.